# WordPress eMails not working

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, email

What should I be looking at? 
No emails from Wordpress (registration/login) even order emails are going to the customer.

I am using Wordpress installed on NGINX VPS. 
I have lifted SMTP block off the server.

All configuration in Wordpress / Woocommerce have been double checked and are correct.

What else should I be looking at and testing?

Thanks all.

Comment: Did you check the Spam folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if youre WP can send out any emails to begin with : https://wordpress.org/plugins/check-email/ is a good one to try.

If you have trouble sending emails with the standard setup you could also try https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/#description and use Gmail or a 3rd party SMTP service to send email. This plugin also has fairly advanced debugging options to work out whats wrong with your setup.